# How can I create a text input with autocomplete and then display data from mysql database in express?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

So, I have a form, in which the user will select inputs. Firstly, I want to create a text input and in this when the user writes for example A, it will suggest every data from the MYSQL database that starts with A etc. The page of the form is **/air_tickets** and then the user will be redirected to another page.

 File structure:

[image]

Inside the **views** folder, there are all my .ejs pages (html).

 **air_tickets.ejs**

```
<form id="form-submit" method="post">
                            <div class="container" id="air-form-container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="from_destination">From: </label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" name="from_destination" class="form-control typeahead tt-query" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" placeholder="City or airport" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="to_destination">To: </label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" name="to_destination" class="form-control" placeholder="City or airport">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-btn">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-btn">Search flights 
                                            <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                       </form>
```

I also found a way with typeahead library but it doesn't work properly. This is the script (I have it inside the air_tickets.ejs file):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
                name: 'typeahead',
                remote: 'http://localhost:3000/search?key=%QUERY',
                limit: 10
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**index.js** (In a routes file)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Air tickets controller
const airTicketsController = require('../controllers/airTicketsController');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', { title: 'Express' });
});

// Air tickets page
router.get('/air_tickets', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('air_tickets', { title: 'Air tickets' });
});

router.get('/search', airTicketsController.fromDestinations);
```

**airTicketsController.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

// DB connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (!!error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('CONGRATS! Database Connected!');
});

//---------------
// autocomplete for from_destination
exports.fromDestinations = (req, res) => {
    connection.query('SELECT from_destination FROM flight where from_destination LIKE "%' + req.query.key + '%"',
        function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var data = [];
            for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                data.push(rows[i].from_destination);
            }
            res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
}
```

**app.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();

// DB connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (!!error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('CONGRATS! Database Connected! (app)');
});

//set views file
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

//set public file
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const routes = require('./server/routes/index');

app.use('/', routes);

// Server Listening
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running at port 3000');
});
```

All the data will come from a MYSQL table called **flight** and have columns like **from_destination** and **to_destination**

 I can't include the typeahead library correctly. But if you know some other way to create the auto-correct text depending on my SQL query, please suggest it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should edit question title as the original problem has progressed and you should ask that in another question.

For `Although, my problem now is how I will take the data from the database` part

1. instead of `form id="form-submit"`, it would be `form action="form-submit"`
2. place a button or input(with type=submit) inside the form.
3. edit your `app.js`'s bodyParser lines to

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

4. add `module.exports = app;` at end of app.js and add `module.exports = connection;` at end of airTicketsController.js (also remove the autofill codes from airTicketsController.js,ejs form and index.js for now to avoid unwanted interference)
5. then you have to read the form by adding this

```
var variable1, variable2;
router.post('/form-submit', function(req,res,next){
    variable1 = req.body.from_destination;
    variable2 = req.body.to_destination
    res.redirect('/yournextpage');
});
```

6. then query your database according to your needs using these two variables on the newpage

```
router.get('/yournextpage', function(req,res, next){
    airTicketsController.query("SELECT * FROM flight WHERE your_column1=? AND your_column2=?",[variable1,variable2],function(err, results, fields){
      res.render('yournextpage', {title: 'flightdata', retrieved: results});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I updated with more details my folder structure and my code..

Comment: It runs, but then at the next page it doesn't display anything, just an empty table (if I enter something like "..WHERE from_destination = 'Paris' AND to_destination = 'London'" in the sql query, then it shows results

Comment: @Themis So, the next page is coming but displays results on manually typing the fields? Try `console.log(variable1)` & variable2 and see if the variables are correctly initialized. Do this in the end of router.post and beginning of router.get. What do you get.

Comment: @Themis also try turning `urlencoded({ extended: true }` to `false` and check if it makes a difference. Although, **if only manually typing the fields instead of ?'s give you result**, then it would be something wrong with your variables

Comment: I tried that and nothing changed. I don't know, I have checked my variables many times

Comment: When i  console.log the variables, it prints undefined on both

Comment: I was req.body the variables at the .get also. Now it works, thanks buddy, you helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this about jQuery autocomplete:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
```

where **tags** is the id of the text input. And it works fine.

 Although, my problem now is how I will take the data from the database